# How to not display p:dialog on selecting "Select One" selectitem in PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I have a p:selectOneMenu and in that list of values where the first value is "Select One" and other values are actual values fetching from db.

When the user selects other values then a dialog box is displaying and fetching respective values, however, after that if user select "Select One" then also displaying the dialog box. Here, I don't want to display dialog box when user select "Select One" from the dropdown.

Xhtml Code:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="drp_modify"
        value="#{BackingBean.Name}" panelStyle="width:180px"
        effect="fade" style="width:180px" filter="true"
        filterMatchMode="startsWith" onchange="PF('dlg_modify').show();"
        title="Add">
        <p:ajax listener="#{BackingBean.onNameChange}"
            update="Name_ID, address" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{BackingBean.nameItemList}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>

<p:dialog header="Modify" widgetVar="dlg_modify" resizable="false">

//// some code

</p:dialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to check the current value of the combobox.

Instead of `onchange="PF('dlg_modify').show();"` you can write:

```
onchange="if(document.getElementById('yourFormId:drp_modify_input').value != '') PF('dlg_modify').show();"
```

where `yourFormId` is the ID of your form and the condition is the value given as an `itemValue` parameter in `f:selectItem`. In your case it's `''`.

Comment: @Neerajkumar even if you set id of your form? strange, for me it works perfectly